# Как вывести в консоль первые три бита числа c#?

Tags: c#

```
        int x = 114;
        string binaryString = Convert.ToString(x, 2);
        Console.WriteLine(binaryString);
```

нужно вывести в консоль первые три бита числа

Comment: `binaryString.Take(3)`

Comment: int x = 114;
            string binaryString = Convert.ToString(x, 2);
            Console.WriteLine(binaryString.Take(3));
так?

Comment: если вам нужны первые три бита слева, то да

Comment: Только Take вернёт IEnumerable, лучше просто Substring взять

Answer (score 0):

```
int x = 114;
string binaryString = Convert.ToString(x, 2);
Console.WriteLine(binaryString.Substring(0,3));
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: А просто `x & 7` (намного короче и безусловно быстрее) чем не подходит?

Comment: @avp, не с того конца.

Comment: @Qwertiy, для меня странная интерпретация "три первых бита", как "три старших бита". Ну в таком случае надо предварительно сдвинуть на 29 вправо

Comment: @avp, какая первая цифра в числе 987? И почему с битами не так же? А вообще, идея со сдвигом интересная. Впрочем, только в моём ответе выводится всегда 3 цифры, остальные на это забили)

Answer (score 0):

https://ideone.com/M5p2eh

```
using System;

public class Test
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    int x = 0x2A000000;
    Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(x, 2).PadLeft(sizeof(int) << 3, '0').Substring(0, 3));
  }
}
```

Comment: В PadLeft достаточно столько нулей, сколько хотим отрезать символов в итоге, не обязательно забивать на всю ширину инта

Comment: @АндрейNOP, даже на 1 меньше можно ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
int TakeHighestBits(int value, byte bits)
{
    byte align = (byte)(32 - bits);
    int result = (int)((uint)value >> align);
    return result;
}
int bits = TakeHighestBits(1110231111,3); //число и необходимое кол-во бит
string s = Convert.ToString(bits,2);
Console.WriteLine(s);
```